# NumberFormatException in Parsing String to Float for Rating Bar?

Tags: android, floating-point, numberformatexception

I am working on Rating Bar in Android in which the value of Rating is fetch from the Web Service. The data which i am getting is in the form of xml like this.

**5.0**

At the time of fetching i am parsing the xml and getting all the values in String. Now I am converting the value of String to Float for Ratings but at that time I am getting NumberFormatException. I don't know why, i have parse other data from String to Double but I didn't get any error at that time but when try to convert from String to Float I don't know why its throwing an exception...

Here is my sample code.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

try {
//Get the xml string from the server
xml = XMLFunctions.getXML(url);
doc = XMLFunctions.XMLfromString(xml);
nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("result");
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Element e = (Element)nodes.item(i);
    map.put(Constants.NAME, XMLFunctions.getValue(e, "name"));
    System.out.println("Rating = " + XMLFunctions.getValue(e, "rating"));
    map.put(Constants.RATING, (Float.parseFloat(XMLFunctions.getValue(e, "rating"))));
    mylist.add(map);
}
```

**ANOTHER TRY:-**

```
String ratingValue = XMLFunctions.getValue(e, "rating");
System.out.println(ratingValue);// it gives me 5.0
float myRating = 0.0f;
myRating = Float.parseFloat(ratingValue); // getting exception here
System.out.println("Rating = **" + myRating + "**");//it gives me Rating = **5.0**
```

**Error Log:-**

```
04-01 08:44:59.986: I/System.out(382): Rating = 5.0
04-01 08:45:00.056: W/System.err(382): java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
04-01 08:45:00.056: W/System.err(382):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseFloat(FloatingPointParser.java:305)
04-01 08:45:00.065: W/System.err(382):  at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:323)
04-01 08:45:00.065: W/System.err(382):  at place.locator.PlaceLocatorActivity$ParseXMLData.doInBackground(PlaceLocatorActivity.java:173)
04-01 08:45:00.065: W/System.err(382):  at place.locator.PlaceLocatorActivity$ParseXMLData.doInBackground(PlaceLocatorActivity.java:1)
04-01 08:45:00.065: W/System.err(382):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
04-01 08:45:00.065: W/System.err(382):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
04-01 08:45:00.065: W/System.err(382):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
04-01 08:45:00.065: W/System.err(382):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
04-01 08:45:00.065: W/System.err(382):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
04-01 08:45:00.065: W/System.err(382):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

I don't know where I am making mistake. If anyone can spot it then please kindly let me know. I know it must be some stupid mistake but some how not able to spot it.

Thanks

Comment: How do we know that the value of "rating" isn't "kumquat"?

Comment: I am sorry but I don't get ur question?

Comment: what does XMLFunctions.getValue(e,"rating") return. i mean string or any thing else

Comment: Its returning String....

Comment: Could there be any characters before or after "5.0" that could cause the exception?  Perhaps use trim()?

Comment: Consider that, if you extract the value from `<tag>\n5.0\n</tag>`, you'll get `\n5.0\n` with many XML toolkits.

Comment: I am using Places API of google and in that there is nothing like that i found. there is one tag of <rating>5.0</rating> from which i am getting my ratings....

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this

```
XMLFunctions.getValue(e, "rating")
```

Use this

```
XMLFunctions.getValue(e, "rating").trim()
```

**Explanation:**
There may be trailing white space in the string you are getting. If there are leading space too, try to use `replace()` method instead. for ex:

```
XMLFunctions.getValue(e, "rating").replace(" ","")
```

If both the methods don't work, try printing the string you are parsing to Float, to check if it's containing any other non numeric character or not.

Comment: I have printed the value using sysout and i don't think that it contains white space still i will try this....The first line in log display the rating which i am getting....

Comment: I mean to say try to use this statement Log.d("Value",XMLFunctions.getValue(e, "rating")); before the parsing statement

Comment: Okk...And also after trying trim and replace i got sysout 2 times. 
1st time it displays Rating = 5.0 &
2nd time it displays Rating = 
why this? I have used only one sysout. for 2nd time it displays blank....

Comment: @Prem -- Sounds like that that second movie is unrated.

Comment: It means that you are trying to parse "Rating=5.0", you can't parse "Rating=", so replace this from the String too. There can be only numbers, no other character (Except dot), in the string to parse.

Comment: See the updated code. I am not parsing Rating=5.0... I just used Rating word in Sysout.....

Comment: You are adding Rating= after it is parsed so I dont think that is the problem.  I think HotLicks is right and the 2nd sysout is empty.  If you catch the NumberFormatException, maybe the error message that will tell you if you are trying to parse an empty string...

Comment: Well you can catch the Exception, as @Mel said, and in the catch block assign 0.0 as the default rating.

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning the value returned from the output to a varaible and then use parseFloat

```
String floatValue = XMLFunctions.getValue(e, "rating");

float myValue = 0.0f;

myValue = Float.parseFloat(floatValue);
```

Comment: @Prem, try it again, but print out the value of `myValue`, surrounding it with `**` characters on both sides so that you see any blanks, tabs, etc.

Comment: I have try that...There is no blank space either of the side.. Its just 5.0 nothing else.....

Comment: I have also added the code you have given in my question with the output but still i'm getting the same exception. Please see the updated code...